# how to get latest nginx using apt - ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, apt

I want to install the latest nginx using apt on ubuntu lucid.

I followed the instructions on the nginx wiki and added the source:

```
echo "deb  http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

the problem is the latest stable version is 0.7.67 but when i use apt-cache show, it shows as 0.7.65

how do i install the latest version using apt?
i had the same problem with php,mysql etc so i've been installing everything from source, but i'm wondering whether i can get all the latest versions with apt.

Comment: still can't get this working, any help appreciated

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy nginx` say?

Comment: shows nothing in version table (after i uncommented out the ubuntu universe files), now can't find nginx (this is progress)

Comment: in my sources file i have: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu lucid main (seems to be ignoring it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you must be especific with the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx=0.7.67-4ppa1
```

Just remember to put the version of nginx from the launchpad package.

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure you follow [ALL the instructions](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxInstall):

```
sudo su -
echo "deb  http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C300EE8C
apt-get update 
apt-get install nginx
```

When you run `apt-get update`, do you get any errors for the nginx repository?  Because the latest version in the [nginx repo](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable) is 0.7.67.

Comment: i followed all the instructions except the last one (install) as i want to ensure its the latest version before installing

Comment: 0.8.50 is latest development release not stable

Comment: Ah, my apologies--the link on the Wiki was incorrect (pointed to the development page).  The latest stable version is located here: https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable; will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: no problem, no errors from the repo, and if i navigate to it via http (http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nginx/), it show the package as 0.7.67, yet apt-cache show tells me different

Comment: when running apt-get update it is saying:
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_GB
i'm guessing ign stands for ignore

Answer (score 0):

Did you do an `$ apt-get update` after adding that line to your `sources.list`? That step is necessary to update apt's local package databases.

Comment: yes i ran apt-get update afterwards

Comment: When you run the update, do you see any entries about it contacting the launchpad repo?

Comment: yes: Get: 3 http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages [14B]